# Node.js: How to add event handler to Connect/Express Server?

Tags: node.js, events, express, connect

I want handle EADDRINUSE how it is described in [API Doc nodejs](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback) but connect/express did not call the error event handler.

here is a example:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect();

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.end('hello world\n');
});

app.on( 'error' , function(e) {
    console.log('error event handler called');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

if I start the server two times, I got
`throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event`

I tested it with connect 2.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.x, `connect()` is no more a constructor for a `net.Server`. 
The 'net.Server' will be returned by the function `listen(...)`.

So to get the example working, it should look like this:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect();

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.end('hello world\n');
});

app.listen(3000).on( 'error' , function(e) {
    console.log('error event handler called');
});
```

see also [connect issue #749](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/749)